# Macbook Pro become buggy after update

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I'm running on Mac OS X (ver 10.7.2) on my Macbook Pro 15. I did an update earlier this morning and after that everything I run fails or runs really slow. Some of my application also don't work properly anymore. My guess is when I did the software update and it rebooted, It failed to complete the installation and just rebooted. So I think the update wasn't installed properly.

Here are some problems that it caused.

1. Whenever I plug a thumb drive or external HDD it's not being mounted. But I can see the drive in Disk Utility. The USB port i think is working because I use it for my wireless mouse. - my guess is the drive for external drives got corrupted.
2. When I try calling someone on Skype it logs me out.
3. There are some lags with the animation. e.g. when i run the Launchpad it has a laggy and harsh animation. It's feels like the animation only has 3 frames so it isn't that smooth.
4. It's really slow!

I just bought this laptop last week and It didn't come with a Mac OS X CD. Is this normal not having a CD?

Some solution I'm planning to do:

1. Reformat/Reset my Mac OS X
   -problem, I don't have the CD
2. Repair the driver
   -problem, I don't know if it's really the driver fault or which driver I should install

Please advice what should I do. The nearest apple store is also far from where I live - so this is my last option to send it back to the store.

Comment: Apple Macs (desktop and laptops) released since the launch of OS X 10.7 Lion do not come with Install DVD or Software Restore DVD. Apple charges for OS X 10.7 Lion sold in a USB thumb drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a **SMC Reset**: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964

You can also re-download the update and try again (=**combo update**): http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1459

Comment: I've tried installing the combo update but It didn't fix it. So I'll be trying to re-install lion instead. thanks!

Comment: Oh, that sucks! Did you create a bootable install USB with lion? I've created one with the installer ``.dmg``. That's much quicker since Lion does not have to be downloaded first. http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/08/make-a-bootable-mac-os-x-10-7-lion-installer-from-a-usb-flash-drive/

Comment: Instructions to re-download Lion: http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/02/re-download-mac-os-x-lion-from-app-store/

Comment: actually i've gone to a LOT of stuff just to re-install the lion again. I now have the lion but wasn't successful in transferring in a thumb drive and in my DVD. my thumb drive is only 4 GB so i think it haven't accomodate the file properly, I've also burned it on a DVD but since it has some problem in mounting. the DVD can't be run or also corrupted. lolz

Comment: so I've decided to use my external hdd instead. but my external HDD wasn't empty, so I need to backup all the files first and copy it, So I can format and partition it to accommodate my lion installer.

Comment: You do need more than 4 GB on the flash drive. I've had a 8GB flash drive. The install DVD is created the same way. But booting from the DVD took several minutes for me..... When I first tried, the install failed. All I had to do to fix was a **PRAM reset** http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379?viewlocale=de_DE. But I don't think this will help you, if the DVD can't even be run. I guess you have a rather serious problem. Maybe it has to do with the hardware. I wish you the best to finally get this fixed!

Answer (score 1):

After re-installing lion the issues still remained. The drives are not being mounted, the animation are still laggy and sluggish, and speaker are disabled even i can hear the chimes from the start up.

After that I brought my MBP to the nearest Apple re-seller that I can find. (btw, The technician is very accommodating to hep me) We tried a lot of stuff and different approach to fix and got lucky in resetting the PRAM (Ctlr + Option + P + R).

Comment: That's what I said in the last comment! =) I also had to do this.

Comment: Hi Matt, Are you referring to SMC? I tried the SMC reset but didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: No, I mean't the PRAM reset. You need to click on "show 2 more comments" on the first answer.

Comment: Darn! I missed that.. I wished i've seen that earlier.. thanks a lot!